# Ratio Test and L = 1

Tags: convergence-divergence

Consider the series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{a^n(n!)^2}$$ with $a > 0$. Determine if the series converges for:

i) a > 4

ii) 0 < a < 4

iii) a = 4

For i) and ii), I will use the ratio test, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{4}{a}$$

So, if $a > 4$, the series converge and, if $0 < a < 4$, the series do not.

iii) If $a = 4$, I am a bit stuck. Can someone please give me some tips?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coefficients are $${2n\choose n}\frac{1}{4^n}\ge \frac{1}{n+1}$$
where ${2n\choose n}$ are [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient), and I used the bound ${2n\choose n}\ge \frac{4^n}{n+1}$.  Hence by comparison with the harmonic series, this diverges.